# Ember-Data making lots of requests (instead of ?ids)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

After upgrading to ember-data-1.0.0-beta.9 I noticed my app was running a lot slower due to making many requests for individual items:

- GET /api/comments/1
- GET /api/comments/2
- ...

instead of batching them as in beta.8 using ?ids:

```
GET /api/comments/?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&....
```

I mistakenly thought that this [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/531/files) had made it's way into beta.9 and that I could set the `fetchBatchSize` param on the RESTAdapter, but no...

How can I get similar batching behavior in beta.9?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to opt into that behavoir now.  See the section on request coalescing here: http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/08/18/ember-data-1-0-beta-9-released.html

Basically, add this to your code:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  coalesceFindRequests: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I should read the blog instead of the changelog.

Comment: Even if this post is quite old, I'm interested why the coalesceFindRequests is turned off by default. Is there a drawback if I turn it on?

Comment: Not that I know of. I think the main reason is because most REST APIs use id endpoints for individual records.